# Sonarube custom configuration

Tags: sonarqube

Currently I am checking PHP code. I have found lot of bugs in

```
Replace or with '||'.  
Add a 'favicon' declaration in this 'header' tag
```

Are there any options to configure or customize what level we can do how we could skip bugs like OR? How to close the resolved bugs? How to perform the user can see the assigned bug only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs. You configure profiles with different rules.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/6966332